# How to map reactive form fields to linear array?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to create data array for Charts JS (as an Angular module). It's just a linear array like `[1,2,3]`.

The source data for this array is a part of reactive form. 
In Json form it looks like so:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "elements": [{
        "id": "1",
        "count": "10"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "count": "20"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "count": "30"
    }]
}
```

I want to get an array with `count` elements: `[10, 20, 30]` but they should be 'tied' to reactive form fields so charts js array should always contain up-to-date elements, if that's possible. I could try to use two way data binding, but I’ve heard that it’s a bad idea to mix reactive forms and `[(ngModel)]`

So the question is: how to map 'count' fields of reactive form to linear array elements and keep them up to date?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve. Subscribe to changes in the form control and update an underlying array? Something like this maybe: https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-valuechanges/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use the `valueChanges` field to get an observable to an array of counts, updating whenever the form is edited:

```
const counts$ = this.formGroup.valueChanges.map(data => {
  return data.elements.map(e => e.count);
});
```

Then tie that observable to your chart library in some way. Here's an example using subscribe (remember to unsubscribe):

```
counts$.subscribe(counts => {
  updateChartJs(counts);
});
```